# MOXy stops serializing with XML annotations

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

Serializing this to JSON works fine in MOXy 2.5.0:

```
public Object[]  destination_addresses;
```

But to also be able to serialize it to XML with JAXB (?), I need an annotation:

```
@XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "destination_address", type = LatLong.class),
              @XmlElement(name = "destination_address", type = Polygon.class)})
public Object[]  destination_addresses;
```

But then MOXy doesn't serialize it at all.  How can I get this to serialize with both MOXy and JAXB?  I'm using Jersey 2.4.1.

MOXy and JAXB work as expected (JAXB can't serialize LatLong) with:

```
@XmlElement(name = "destination_address", type = Polygon.class)
public Object[]  destination_addresses;
```

(I'm new to all this, so let me know if there's useful info I left out.)

**EDIT:** not sure why MOXy would care, but here's LatLong & Polygon:

```
public class LatLong {
    public double lat, lng;
}
public class Polygon {
    @XmlElement
    protected List<LatLong> points = new ArrayList<LatLong>();
    public String toString(){return points.toString();}
}
```

**EDIT2:** I've drastically changed Polygon to get the XML I want: [MOXy adds type and uses toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20395423/192798) .  Now MOXy throws:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [] or [getLatOrLongs] is not defined in the object [com.buzzhives.Routing.Hive.Polygon].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.buzzhives.Routing.Hive.Polygon.([Lcom.buzzhives.Routing.Hive.Polygon$LatOrLong;)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeObjectMapping[latOrLongs]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.buzzhives.Routing.Hive.Polygon --> [])

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:689)
```

**EDIT3:** I've put `Polygon` back the way it was (i.e. disregard EDIT2), found an unrelated bug in MOXy (see comment below), and changed `destination_addresses` to `List<Object>` instead of `Object[]`.  `Polygon` is now serialized ok (using `points`), but the simple `LatLong` is not serialized at all.

**EDIT4:** Debugging MOXy is very painful.  I found that it was serializing the `LatLong` and the `Polygon` to two separate arrays called `destination_address` instead of putting them both in one array.

Comment: What do your `LatLong` and `Polygon` classes look like?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I've added them.  MOXy serializes with toString() while JAXB serializes the XmlElement.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I've totally changed `Polygon` and now MOXy throws an exception I don't understand

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, line 141 of `XMLChoiceObjectMappingNodeValue.java`: should that be `theClass` instead of `valueClass`?